# Seeking Canadian postal code geometries

Tags: data, canada, postal-code

Where can I find the shapefiles for Canadian postal codes?

Comment: This Q&A has many elements of a discussion mixed with what appears to be some valuable content.  I've converted it to Community Wiki and applied a Wiki Lock to it in order to try and get a more canonical answer to emerge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Postal Code FSA Conversion files will be freely available as of Oct 24, 2012 as per the new data freedom initiative.

See [Census geography](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/index-eng.cfm) page of Statistics Canada for details.

---

A list of all Canadian postal codes (includes city, province, latitude, longitude) is available here:

http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1

Geocoder collected the postal codes by crowd-sourcing.

---

Canadian postal codes are not available for free download.  You can either purchase the [PostCode Conversion File from Statistics Canada](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/bsolc/olc-cel/olc-cel?catno=92-153-GWE&lang=eng) or one of many value-added data sets from providers like [DMTI Spatial](http://www.dmtispatial.com/en/Products/CanMapProductSuite/PlatinumPostalCodeSuite.aspx).

Comment: Both links to the StatsCan website and DMTI are dead.

Answer (score 11):

As a heads-up, they changed the projection format between 2011 and 2016 in case you are upgrading your local data from 2011 to 2016. The 2011 shape file is NAD83 (4269), but the 2016 *seems* to be using Lambert projection (3348). I say *seems* because when I load the shape file it doesn't specifically seem to say the exact EPSG/SRID. I ended up converting the shape file to be 4326 so that it's the same as Google Maps.

---

2016 FSA Census Boundary files are now available (as of Sept 13, 2017 according to their site).

---

Stats Canada has since released the Forward Sortation Areas Boundary files (as of February 5, 2013 according to their site).

[Download Page for all 2011 Census Boundary Files](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm)

[Download Page for all 2016 Census Boundary Files](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm)

---

Statistics Canada has a page dedicated to making available different Shape files regarding Canadian Boundaries, both Geographical and Digital. (link is the same as the one mentioned above)

http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm

If you only need the geographic center of the postalcodes however (instead of the boundary), check out the free database at http://geocoder.ca/.
You can obtain the approx center of the FSA from this as well by grouping them by the first three digits of the PostalCode and then averaging the Latitude/Longitude. SQL would help do this much easier if you import the data into a database first.

Here's a query do do what I mean.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM zipcodeset WHERE LEN(PostalCode) = 3)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO zipcodeset(PostalCode, Latitude, Longitude)
    SELECT LEFT(PostalCode,3), Avg(Latitude), Avg(Longitude)
    FROM zipcodeset
    GROUP BY LEFT(PostalCode,3)
END
```

FSA Boundary shapefiles are now published.

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to convert the shape file into NAD83? I'm trying to make them work with Google Maps too and would love it if you could share as I'm lost.

Answer (score 4):

The FSA shapefiles are up now at http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm I just downloaded them, now only if there was an LDU shapefile available...

Here is a picture of the LDU shapefile loaded in QGIS and zoomed into Stanley Park in Vancouver BC:

[image: LDU shapefile of Stanley Park in Vancouver, BC]

The data is available through the Platinum Postal Suite, v2008.3, 2008 which I was able to access through my university account. The LDU data is for all of Canada and is broken up into a per province structure, unfortunately you have to download all of them at the same time though which makes it larger than 1 Gb.

Answer (score 2):

you can purchase Canadian Postal Codes and FSA Boundaries from Geografx Digital Mapping Services info@geografx.ca , www.geografx.ca  or www.geografx.com

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial available canada postal code data as well, they are usually more precise and up to date. Can refer to IGEOCODE postal code products at http://www.igeocode.com/products/capostalcodes/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I've also worked with another company out of Ontario called AGSI. Their database has FSA and LDU boundaries along with address points.

Comment: http://locationwarehouse.info/products/postal-code-products/ seems to be their product.

Comment: @Boris are they generating the LDU boundaries using an internal process? Or by the postal ldu codes(lat and lng)?