# Plotting Postal Codes from .csv Files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, postal-code

I have Canadian postal code data that I would like to plot.  This data is currently stored in a simple .csv file.  At the moment the only other data I have is FSA data from Statistics Canada.  Is there any way I can use this data, or is there other data I should have, to properly plot the postal codes from the .csv file onto a map of Canada?  There may be a very simple solution to this, since I am quite new to QGIS.

UPDATE: I found [this site](http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1), which has free postal code data along with latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: what geographical information do you have in your .csv? just postcode?

Comment: @Mapperz Just postal code unfortunately.  Is it important that I have more information than that?

Comment: @114 I think you'll just get point data from any successful geocode - is that what you're after?

Comment: @mapBaker Yes, though if you have a suggestion for a shape file to lay the information on instead of google maps that would be great!

Comment: I thought Stats Canada would have a postal code file out there somewhere... @Mapperz do you know?

Comment: @mapBaker As well, and I just realized this, I will need latitude and longitudes for each of these postal codes in order to use them, won't I?

Comment: Well you can find the lat/lon's on this site: http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1 but for some reason the actual postal code polygon shapefiles are not available for free! Check this thread too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41/where-can-i-find-canadian-postal-code-geometries

Comment: Purchase of Postcodes (Polygon Area) has to be made to Canada Post (it is not cheap) - See the older GIS-SE Question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41/where-can-i-find-canadian-postal-code-geometries

Answer (score 1):

Canada Post keeps a tight reign on its claimed copyright of Canadian postal codes. The site 'geocoder.ca' referred to in the update is one of several sites that Canada Post has dragged into the Canadian court system. Basically, Canada Post makes money selling the information. Canada Post has gone so far and trade mark the spelling 'Postal code' (note the 'c' in code is lowercase). They claim exclusive right to this phrase.

Even while Canada Stats has data at the FSA/LDU level, the public data is ONLY available at the FSA level:

http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comprehensive/comp-csv-tab-dwnld-tlchrgr.cfm?Lang=E

The same copyright is true in US that zip codes are copyright property of the US Postal Service. But, in the US the crowd sourced and other reversed engineer compilations NOT derived from the USPS source, the USPS has never (and does not expect to) claimed copyright infringement.

And again, starting with the 2000 census the US Census stopped using actual zip codes and use ZCTAs (sort like zip codes - lol).

I have my own non-USPS derived compilations which I make publicly available (CC0) at:
http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#cityzip