# Finding/buying Civic Address Data for all of Canada

Tags: data, geocoding, address, canada

I work for a company that is looking to buy all the civic address data for Canada.
I've been Googling around and I have yet to find a solution that is not pay per request.

We need it so that it can be integrated in to an ArcGIS server.

What we want to do with the data is tie to in to a Geodatabase where people will be able to search their address and have information pop up about their house. We have the metadata for each location but our current addressing system is partially interpolated/inaccurate (not accurate to the level that we'd like).

We're looking for source data.

Comment: For the most part, civic address information is managed at the provincial level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find Canadian postal code geometries?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41/where-can-i-find-canadian-postal-code-geometries)

Comment: @dassouki I get the impression from the question they want to do local geocoding, which requires a lot more than just postal code boundaries, so I'm not sure this would really qualify as a duplicate. Detoxify, can you expand your question a bit to clarify exactly what you want to do with whatever data you're looking for? Geocoding isn't typically done against an *address* list, though it can be; it's done against street line data. For all of Cananda you're looking at a huge dataset to manage, which is why it's so often provided as a service instead.

Comment: @ChrisW Good point, I'll keep my comment and close until the OP clarifies.

Comment: BTW, if it *is* seeking a geocoding database, then it'd be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14069

Comment: @dassouki I don't think Postal Codes and Civic Addresses are the same thing so this probably isn't a duplicate =)

Comment: Close vote retracted

Answer (score 3):

This might be better as a wiki.

In **British Columbia**, civic addressing is maintained by [local governments](https://www.civicinfo.bc.ca/111.asp?showall=yes) (ie, municipalities and regional districts). Depending on what your use is for the data, they can often be obtained by simple data requests directly to those local governments if it's not publicly accessible already.

The data you get might not be under an open data license like the [City of Vancouver](http://data.vancouver.ca/datacatalogue/index.htm#i), Surrey and maybe Banff, does and some other municipalities.

Most local governments are now sharing their civic address information with the Integrated Cadastral Information Society for their AddressBC database that you can [become a member](http://www.icisociety.ca/members/join/) of for a hefty annual fee.

OpenData BC also lists a type of [RESTful physical address geocoder service for BC](http://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/physical-address-geocoding-web-service) that might be useful too.

Comment: Vancouver has ICIS address data in the opendata catalogue portal http://data.vancouver.ca/datacatalogue/icis.htm

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks, that's actually where the "City of Vancouver" link goes to.

Comment: I actually already have all the civic address data for BC. I've used that site countless times already, its an amazing resource.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Postal Conversion Code File](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/olc-cel/olc.action?lang=en&ObjId=92-154-X&ObjType=2). Other companies do provide their own version of it though with other socioeconomic data.

Comment: That doesn't have the level of detail for civic address points, its more of a block level of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

**CanMap Address Points**

> Integrate Canada's most comprehensive collection of individual address
>   points into your business application(s) or GPS devices to improve the
>   accuracy of your results. Specifically designed and formatted for easy
>   integration through our OEM content model, CanMap Address Points
>   includes the definitive Canadian address database, high precision
>   geographic coordinates, land use status and other critical
>   location-based information.

http://www.dmtispatial.com/Software-And-Data/CanMap.html

Sample Addresses from text file in FME data inspector

[image]

Notes:
but from experience this data can be quite dated more so in rural areas.

you might find it better to go through local government some areas even have address point data as opendata.

Comment: I'm not looking for a geocoding service, I'm looking for data to use internally. We actually already have their data integrated in to our system but as you said, it is a bit dated. Ideally accurate to rooftops. Thank you for your input though, I appreciate it.

Comment: This is data not a service the sample data is address point txt here http://offers.dmtispatial.com/rs/dmtispatial/images/CanMap_Address_Points_Text.zip

Comment: added screenshot of the address point data from the sample data link above

Answer (score 0):

https://geocoder.ca/?register=1&capostal=1 - Canada Postal Address Database (26983726 records as of 2019-11-28 13:43:13)